# Why a Qt SIGNAL(clicked(bool) does not same with a really mouse clicked behavior?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I add a QPushButton in my widget and set it to checkable.
and add some codes in its slot function like below.
if I click this button1 by mouse, all is working fine.
But, if I connect it with a signal by:

```cpp
connect(ui->button2,SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),this,SLOT(on_button1_clicked(bool)));
```

and click on button2 by mouse,
the on_button1_clicked(bool checked) executed, but, the button1 background color not change.

Did anyone give some suggestion?

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_button1_clicked(bool checked)
{
    if(checked)
    {       
       //some work here.....
        ui->button1->setText(tr("on "));
       //.......
    }
    else
    {
       //some work here.......
        ui->button1->setText(tr("off "));
       //......
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you call `ui->button2->setCheckable(true);`?

Comment: Yes. I do.  I call ui->button2->setCheckable(true); in the constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the background color does not change'? Do you want the button1 to look as if it is being pressed?

Comment: Yes. it is. both of  button1 and button2 was set to checkable by qt Designer. when I press it down, its background color will change automaticly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should connect your `button2` to `button1`'s `setChecked(bool)` slot instead.

I just looked at [the source of `QAbstractButton::setChecked(bool)`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractbutton.cpp.html#_ZN15QAbstractButton10setCheckedEb) and it does emit a signal, though not `clicked(bool)`, but `toggled(bool)`.

So rename your `on_button1_clicked(bool)` to `on_button1_toggled` and change your connection to:

```
connect(ui->button2, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), ui->button1, SLOT(setChecked(bool)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. Martin Hennings. it worked. After i modify the codes as your suggestion. You are great.